# AngularJS: Controller executes twice when I visit a page and I focus a select element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have the next issue:
I have a form and a controller. The controller has the function for submit the form and an alert. I can submit the form and when I submit it, I go to a new page. If I go back to the form, everything is OK and the alert displays. But if I focus any input, the alert displays again and I don't know why.
Some code:
HTML:

```html
<form name="formulario" role="form" class='col-xs-12' novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Terminal</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="terminal" ng-model="terminal" required>
      /* option values */
     </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Producto</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="producto" ng-model="producto" required>
      </* option values */
     </select>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type='hidden' ng-value="enviar_peticion" ng-model="accion" />
     <button ng-disabled="formulario.$invalid" ng-click="enviarPedido()" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12">Realizar pedido</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

JS (I use routing for the controller):

```js
.controller("pedidosCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$location", function($scope, $http, $location) {
  navigator.notification.alert("MSG", "OK");
  
  $scope.enviarPedido=function(){
   /*JSON CALL*/

  };
 }])
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You should set ng-submit="enviarPedido()" on the form tag, and instead of your button you should have a input of type submit, which will trigger the form to be submitted.

Comment: I try it but... it didn't work. The behaviour is the next: 1. I go to the page. 2. The alert shows. 3. I go back. 4. I go to the page again. 5. The alert shows. 6. I pick the select, I can see the options. 7. I choose an options and click "done" in my iphone, but at this time, the alert shows and the select remain empty. 8. If I pick the select, I can choose an option and everything is ok.

Comment: What is your logic for going to another page?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my comment.

Comment: I have seen when I go to the page for the first time, "form.$valid" is FALSE, but if I go back and go to the page again, "form.$valid" is TRUE. And then, if I pick the select and pick one option and "Done", "form.$valid" turns to FALSE again.

Comment: Now I have put a $watch in my controller and I can see the controller is executing 10 times, but my model doesn't change.